# Swipe from one ViewController to another with Swift

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, swift, swipe

I'm currently trying to connect different ViewControllers with each other using Swift, but I'm stuck and would appreciate some help in order to proceed.

What I have now is a main view and when you swipe to the right you would enter another view (like Snapchat works). I've done this using the tutorial found [here](https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-swipe-view-with-swift-44fa83a2e078).

Basically I have a ContainerViewController that store two subviews in its view hierarchy. So I can swipe back and forth between Subview 1 and Subview 2 (see illustration for an idea). Subview 2 has a button that 'modally' loads another ViewController. My question is, if it is possible, how could I make it so that when I swipe left in the "modal ViewController" I would swipe back to Subview 1?

[image]

Here is my code that controls the transition from Subview 2 (BViewController) and the modal ViewController (InfoVC):

```
class BViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var item: UIBarButtonItem!
    var info: InfoVC = InfoVC(nibName: "InfoVC", bundle: nil )

    func tabBar( tabBar: UITabBar!, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem!){
        if item.tag == 2{ // we are in new view controller
            info.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
            self.presentViewController(info, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        println("info hash \(info.hashValue)")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

And this is my ContainerViewController class where the ScrollView/swipe mechanism is made.

```
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {

    // Outlet used in storyboard
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView?;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();

        // 1) Create the three views used in the swipe
        var AVc: AViewController = AViewController(nibName: "AViewController", bundle: nil)
        var BVc: BViewController = BViewController(nibName: "BViewController", bundle: nil)

        // 2) Add in each view to the container view hierarchy
        //    Add them in opposite order since the view hieracrhy is a stack

        self.addChildViewController(BVc);
        self.scrollView!.addSubview(BVc.view);
        BVc.didMoveToParentViewController(self);

        self.addChildViewController(AVc);
        self.scrollView!.addSubview(AVc.view);
        AVc.didMoveToParentViewController(self);

        // 3) Set up the frames of the view controllers to align
        //    with eachother inside the container view
        var adminFrame :CGRect = AVc.view.frame;
        adminFrame.origin.x = adminFrame.width;
        BVc.view.frame = adminFrame;

        var BFrame :CGRect = BVc.view.frame;
        BFrame.origin.x = 2*BFrame.width;

        // 4) Finally set the size of the scroll view that contains the frames
        var scrollWidth: CGFloat  = 2 * self.view.frame.width
        var scrollHeight: CGFloat  = self.view.frame.size.height
        self.scrollView!.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth, scrollHeight);
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

In summary:

What I can do already is to scroll from AViewController to BViewController (back and forth) and go from BViewController to InfoVC by pressing the tab bar item/button. What I then cannot figure out is to swipe backwards in InfoVC and reach AViewController with the same transition as when I swipe between AViewController and BViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to your InfoVC. The easiest way, in Interface Builder, is to drag one from your Object Library onto your InfoVC. You'll see a new icon for it appear in the toolbar at the top of your IB scene. Select it, then in the Attributes Inspector, choose which direction you want the swipe to go--in your case, it's probably left to right.

Next, implement `touchesBegan()` and `touchesEnded()` methods in your InfoVC, and use the locations of the events to determine whether the user has swiped whatever distance you specify between the start and end points. If `touchesEnded()` is at least that distance away, then you can dismiss your InfoVC by removing it from its parent, `BViewController`.

Comment: I'm not at a Mac to try it out right now, but would that provide the same transition effect between the two ViewControllers as there would be when transitioning between AViewController and BViewController in the UIScrollView?

Comment: Not by default. You're not really swiping between `AViewController` & `BViewController`; you're just shifting the contents of a scroll view. Instead, since you're tracking the swipe touches, you can create a custom transition to slide `InfoVC` off to the right and bring `BViewController` in from the left.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load the ViewController from your storyboard
2. Embed the BViewController in a UINavigation controller.
3. That will allow you to do all segues in a storyboard kind of fashion

   ```
   // lets try to load them from the storyboard
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navController") as UINavigationController
   var BVc = navigationController
   ```

This will be a good first step. In your BVc prepare for Segue enabling and disabling the scrolling as it will interfere with the containerviews swiping. ReEnable it in your BVc's view did appear.

```
var parentVC = self.navigationController?.parentViewController as ContainerViewController
parentVC.scrollView?.scrollEnabled = false
```

You might have to do some additional work to re-receive swipe events in your modal, I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using UIPageViewController, it was created for tasks like this and you can hide the dots bar by deleting these methods:

```
presentationCountForPageViewController
presentationIndexForPageViewController
```

For the button to work you need to add:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [AnyObject], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
```

Here is a good tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bltsDG2ENQ